# Javascript function parameter names at time of call?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, extract

I know this is a *really* long shot, but I figure I'd ask: Is there a way to to find the names of the variables passed as parameters in a function call?

Assuming I have:

```
function test(tmp1, tmp2) {
  // ...
}

var a;
var b;

test(a, b);
```

I'd like to get an array like so: `[a, b]`. Strings would also be acceptable: `["a", "b"]`.

I do *not* want `["tmp1", "tmp2"]`, which I know I can get by parsing the string representation of the function.

I'm asking because I'm trying to to improve my [caseclass.js](http://github.com/pr1001/caseclass.js) library with real extractors (see the link for more information). I understand that only objects are passed by reference, so I'm trying to find a work around to pass the values extracted back to the placeholder variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question tagged scala?

Comment: I've removed the scala and case-class tags. Either explain why it has to do with them or drop them.

Comment: Because my caseclass.js library is trying to mimic Scala's case classes. This question is specifically because I'm trying to implement extractors in the matching.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could look into the stacktrace caused by an exception or error, but I'm not certain it would work, and it would probably work differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to take a look at the [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function... but I've never done something like you describe with javascript. I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid eval, though you'r right that it might be the only way possible. If so, I think I'll avoid it – too hacky then!

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:

```
var a = { name: 'a', value: 'foo' };
var b = { name: 'b', value: 'bar' };

test(a, b);

function test(tmp1, tmp2)
{
   var paramArray = [ tmp1.name, tmp1.name ];
}
```

Comment: That works but requires the user to specify the variable name, which I had hoped to avoid. I may have to do that...